# Xamarin Forms Custom Bindable Command type mismatch

Tags: mvvm, properties, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a custom view called `PINControl`, which shows a PIN entry with a configurable amount of digits.
The XAML I'd like to use in my `ContentPage` is

```xml
<local:PINControl x:Name="PIN" 
    PINLength="5" 
    PINCompleteCommand="{Binding CompletePIN}" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

My BindableProperties in the PINControl are:

```cs
public class PINControl : StackLayout
{
    private const int LENGTH_DEFAULT = 4;

    public static readonly BindableProperty PINLengthProp = BindableProperty.Create<PINControl, int> (c => c.PINLength, LENGTH_DEFAULT);
    public static readonly BindableProperty PINCompleteCommandProp = BindableProperty.Create<PINControl, ICommand> (c => c.PINCompleteCommand, null);

    public ICommand PINCompleteCommand {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue (PINCompleteCommandProp); }
        set { SetValue (PINCompleteCommandProp, value); }
    }
    public int PINLength {
        get { return (int)GetValue (PINLengthProp); }
        set { SetValue (PINLengthProp, value); }
    }
```

My ViewModel contains

```cs
public ICommand CompletePIN { get; set; }

public PINViewModel ()
{
    CompletePIN = new Command<string> ((pin) => {
        var e = pin.ToString();
    });
}
```

It does not seem to have a problem with the `PINLength`, but the `PINCompleteCommand` is giving me the following error:

> Cannot assign property "PINCompleteCommand": type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "System.Windows.Input.ICommand"

I cannot find a solution for this problem. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hover over where your using ICommand / Command.  You may have a conflict with the 'using' statements by sounds of it, picking it up somewhere where you didn't intend?

Comment: @pete I have `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` and `Xamarin.Forms.Command`. So no troubles in the usings I guess.

Comment: Are you able to package up the solution so I can run it and take a quick look?  If so, my contact details are on my profile page.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good practice to follow while naming BindableProperties, which is to name it `propertynameProperty`.

In your case, when the Xaml parser encounter this instruction

```
PINCompleteCommand="{Binding CompletePIN}"
```

it first tries to find a public static BindableProperty with name PINCompleteCommandProperty, fails, then look for a normal property named PINCompleteCommand, succeed, and try to assign the value (a `Binding`) to the property (an `ICommand`) and generate the message you are seeing.

Fix your BindableProperty naming, and you should be fine.

Comment: you are right..i encountered the issue and thats where learning happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's applicable to the OP situation or not, but it's worth noting that this will also arise if the ViewModel/BindingTo property is the same name as the BindableProperty name and you bind the two together.

eg.

CustomControl
-> PinLengthCommand/PinLengthCommandProperty

ViewModel
  -> PinLengthCommand

Just change the name of the property on the viewmodel and it will run OK.